# I'm trying to send a local notification to the user when they enter a specific location

Tags: swift2, ios9, uilocalnotification

I'm not sure how to have this local notification to be triggered at a specific location, can someone please help?

Please find the below code for more information.

```
func notification() {

    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    notification.alertBody = "Turn phone on silent"

    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    notification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(5)

    notification.repeatInterval = .Day

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    print("Notification was sent")


  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by specific location? Do you mean by specific latitude longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make location based Notification you should use geofencing with the help of CLLocation manager and startMonitoringForRegion, import CoreLocation and rewrite notification method as follows:

```
 func setNotificationForLatitude(latitude:CLLocationDegrees, longitude:CLLocationDegrees, identifier: String) {
   var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   let regionToBeMointored = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), radius: 100.0, identifier: identifier)
   //Configure Region depending on required latitude,longitude.
   regionToBeMointored.notifyOnExit = false
   //Configure event to be triggered on entry and exit 
   locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(regionToBeMointored)
 }
```

In AppDelegate Implement locationManagerdidEnterRegion delegate method and inside this method configure local push notification:

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)
 {
   let localGeoNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
   localGeoNotification.alertBody = "You have entered the region"
   localGeoNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
   localGeoNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localGeoNotification)     
   locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)                  
 }
```